# How to find which cells a shape touches as it get rotated?

Tags: geometry

Imagine a shape composed by squares on a grid.  This shape is rotated by 90 degrees, clockwise or counterclockwise.  How can one find which cells this shape touches as it executes its rotation?

In the image below for instance, imagine the shape must be rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I crossed with a blue X all the cells it touches. I'm wondering if there is a way to generalize this rule and find it for a given shape.

So far I've found that the origin touches all cells orthogonal to it. So, I'm imagining there must be a solution by thinking about the distance between a given square and its distance to the origin? I'm not quite sure.

[image: Illustration, done in Unity]

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but only a partial answer.
Let $x_0$ denote the centre of rotation, and consider how the distance to $x_0$ changes as you travel along the boundary of your shape $S$. Along any straight edge of your shape, the distance to $x_0$ is maximised at one of the ends of that edge.

Similarly, for each grid square $G$, you can compute the minimum distance from $x_0$ to the closest point $g$ in $G$ to $x_0$. Then as $S$ rotates through $360^\circ$, $S$ overlaps $G$ if and only if the distance from $x_0$ to some $p \in \partial S$ is less than or equal to the distance from $x_0$ to $g$. If $S$ is a polygon, $S$ overlaps $G$ as it rotates through $360^\circ$ if and only if the distance from $x_0$ to one of the corners of $S$ is less than the distance from $x_0$ to $g$.

Lastly, consider what happens if we rotate only $90^\circ$. Clearly, $S$ overlaps $G$ if any of the vertices of $S$ within that $90^\circ$ overlaps $G$. Second, consider a side $s$ of $S$, where one vertex $v_1$ of $s$ is within the $90^\circ$ angle of $g$ and the other vertex $v_2$ isn't. As a point $p$ travels along $s$, the distance $dist(p,x_0)$ decreases until a minimum, then increases (or only increases or only decreases). Therefore, you only need to consider $dist(x_0,v_1)$ and $dist(x_0,g)$, as well as considering whether $s$ overlaps $G$ at the beginning and end of the rotation. Lastly, you need to consider if $s$ can overlap $G$ if the triangle formed by $s$ and $x_0$ does not overlap $g$. It can, but I suspect that if $G$ is a square, it only can if $S$ overlaps $G$ at the beginning or end of its rotation.